# Can't access fields of a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

The following Javascript function returns a JS object:

```
function getCookies() {
    var result = {};
    var cookie = {};
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        cookie = cookies[i].split('=');
        result[cookie[0]] = cookie[1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

When I tried to access its fields the "easy" way, all I got was "undefined", eg:

```
var c = getCookies();
alert(c.a_cookie_name);
alert(c['a_cookie_name']);
```

The only way I could access the keys and values was iterating through the fields, eg:

```
for(cookieName in c){
  alert(c[cookieName]);
}
```

The question is how to access the fields without iterating?

Thank you.

P.S. The keys and values do exist, I can see the object fields with console.log(getCookies()) in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are properly accessing fields the problem is that hte fields you're accessing don't exist.  It' looks like the property named `a_cookie_name` simply doesn't exist on the object.

**EDIT**

Given that the Chrome console shows the properties as existing, one possibility to consider is there is white space in the names of the properties.  This could explain the difference as the white space would be hard to see in the console.  To test that out try the following.  It will make the spaces a bit more visible if they are there

```
for (var cookieName in c) {
  alert('"' + cookieName + '"="' + c[cookieName] + '"');
}
```

Comment: In the Google Crome's console i see that the function returns an object with the correct field names and values.

Comment: @vicuv have you considered there is white space in the output? This would make it invisible in the Chrome console display but would prevent you from accessing the property by name wihtout the spaces

Comment: @vicuv i've updated my alert sample to help detect the possibility of white space in the property name

Comment: Thank you! The white space is exactly what it was!